# How to remove a function after it has been executed once

Tags: c#, winforms, function, methods, c#-2.0

I have a function to be executed under a radio button checked event, but it has to be done only once. In subsequent radio button checked events, my function shouldn't be called.

```
void rb_CheckedChanged(x, y)
{
    LoadSomeData(); //need to load only once.
    // rest of the code; to be executed every single time..
}
```

Note:

1. I want `LoadSomeData()` to be executed only under radio button event.
2. I can set an integer member variable, and do count++, n check if == 1 etc. Or a boolean flag. That's not what I'm looking for.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a list of function names that you would like to call in your event, then get the method name from list, using reflection call the method you are interested in and then remove that method name from the list... Next time, when the event is called again, the method won't be executed before it won't be in the list.. something like:

```
List<string> listMethod = new List<string>();
listMethod.Add("LoadSomeData");
```

then

```
void rb_CheckedChanged(x, y)
{
string methodName = listMethod[0];
Type.InvokeMember(
                    methodName,
                    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | 
                        BindingFlags.Static,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
listMethod.Clear(); //or remove what ever you want
}
```

You can get information about dynamic method invoking from: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CallMethodNameInString.aspx

Comment: Is there a method to remove functions like we do for event handlers?

Comment: if you mean add event handler (+=) and remove event handler, then there isnt any

Comment: `An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'System.Type.InvokeMember(string, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, object, object[])'` Why do i get this error?

Comment: You have to create an object of type 'Type', you can't call Type.InvokeMember(...) because its not a static method.. I recommend you to go through the article whose link i have posted in my asnwer.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a [hidden field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx) and use that as a flag to determine whether you should run `LoadSomeData` again. Something like:

```
void rb_CheckedChanged(x, y)
{
    if (hiddenField.Value == "False")
    {
        LoadSomeData(); //need to load only once.
        hiddenField.Value = true.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
         // Do nothing.
    }
    // rest of the code; to be executed every single time..
}
```

And in your page:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenField" Value="False" />
```

Comment: Hello, what is this hidden field? Of what type?

Comment: OK I dunno anything regarding `<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenField" Value="False" />`. I wouldnt go for it. I was thinking of something like how we remove eventhandlers. Can we do that with functions?

Comment: I added a link to my answer to the `HiddenField` class. You'll find an example there too.

Comment: I assumed you were inside an aspx page? But that doesn't seem to be the case. Is this a Windows forms application?

Comment: Yes it is WinForm. Sorry for the delay. I was trying out codes given here

Comment: No problem, if you ever need similar functionality for ASPX, you know where to look :)

Answer (score 1):

i think option 2 is your best choice, have a sticky bool around it.

```
private bool stickyFlag = true;

void rb_CheckedChanged(x,y)
{
    if (true == stickyFlag)
    {
        LoadSomeData();
        stickyFlag = false;
    }
    ....
    // rest of the code; to be executed every single time..
}
```

Comment: @nawfla: I know, but i believe this is the only way to do it, as far as i know it

Comment: @nawfal: And what is it you're looking for exactly ? Magic ? There is no provision for what you're trying to do in either the framework or the language, so what else do you want ? Using a flag is the easiest way to achieve what you're after. Anything else would only serve as a fun thing to research and try. Is this what you're after ?

Comment: @mrlucmorin, certainly not magic buddy, after all this is not Ruby ;). It was an effort to know if there are any better/standard/professional/elegant/right coding techniques in .net or any sort of compiler trick to handle situations like these, after all this is not a one-off case. Something like this would stumble on my mind since I came to know about removing delegates and eventhandlers. Those are so handy tricks. Why wouldn't I ponder anything like that about its siblings? By the way two cool methods has been posted by Waqas and hcb..

Comment: @nawfal, I totally agree that the solutions proposed by Waqas and hcb are very novel, but if you look down into both, you see that they still rely on some kind of flag indicating whether to execute the code or not, so that's why I asked what you were after. I was certainly not discouraging you from asking questions. Just trying to understand the problem you're trying to solve with voodoo ;-)

Comment: Yes they do rely on flag, but aren't they more of standard solutions? I had three such occasions to avoid unwanted loading of data, and hence creating a list of methods (by Waqas) was terrific for me..

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Attribute with PostSharp [RunOnce]

this attribut may have a property which indicates wether the method has already been triggered

[PostSharp Link](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/)

Answer (score 1):

i'd go for the second option, but you could use delegates:

```
public event Action doLoadSomeData; 

void onLoad(sender, args)
{
    doLoadSomeData += LoadSomeData();
}

void rb_CheckedChanged(x, y)
{
    if (doLoadSomeData != null)
    {
         doLoadSomeData(); //need to load only once.
    }
    doLoadSomeData = null;
    // rest of the code; to be executed every single time..
}
```